# Magento 2 : preference for reviews post controller error:Type Error occurred when creating object:

Tags: magento2, controllers, product-review, preference

I get this error **Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object:**
I created a prefernce for review controller **Post** and added the construct method in it with the additional code : below

```
/** @var Filesystem */
    protected $fileSystem;

    /** @var UploaderFactory */
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->fileSystem = $filesystem;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```

Below code is magento core review post controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Review\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;

/**
 * Class Post
 */
class Post extends ProductController implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Submit new review action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
        if ($data) {
            $rating = [];
            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }
        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
        }
        if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
            $review->unsetData('review_id');

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {
                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                        ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                        ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                        ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                        ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                        ->save();

                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        $this->ratingFactory->create()
                            ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                            ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You submitted your review for moderation.'));
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            }
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->reviewSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl ?: $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Below code is the review post controller in my app code directory which I created with a prefernce:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace CompanyName\Reviews\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Post
 */
class Post extends ProductController implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

    /** @var Filesystem */
    protected $fileSystem;

    /** @var UploaderFactory */
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->fileSystem = $filesystem;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    

    /**
     * Submit new review action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
        if ($data) { 
            $rating = [];
            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }
        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
        }
        if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
            $review->unsetData('review_id');

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {


                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                        ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                        ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                        ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                        ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                        ->save();
//print_r('data');exit;
                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        $this->ratingFactory->create()
                            ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                            ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }
                    

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You submitted your review for moderation.'));
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t post your review right now 1.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t post your review right now 2.'));
                }
            }
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->reviewSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl ?: $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

I have removed the **generated folder** and compiled **di** but still getting this error, what could be the possible solution to add construct method ? any idea/suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: just an idea but what if you had the parent construct call in your custom construct ? 
More likely the construct isn't defined cause it's defines in the parent of the parent class or something like that ? I might be wrong but i've never seen a class extended with no parent construct call yet.

Comment: @Claims I added the parent parents constructor in my code and getting this error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in